# Check if a file exists in multiple directories

Tags: powershell

I have 100(ish) .pdf's that I've copied into 88 different folders. I'm now left with 1 .pdf and I think I may have accidently copied 1 .pdf into two folders.

I tried making a script that runs through all of the folders and check if the file already exists in the that folder. However, I think I may have gone into a rabbit hole with the code:

```
  $ParentFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\pc90555\c$\Users\mmdu\OneDrive - COWI\Documents\kort2021" 

$childItem = @()

Foreach ($subFolders in $ParentFolder){
    
    $childItem += Get-ChildItem -Path "\\pc90555\c$\Users\mmdu\OneDrive - COWI\Documents\kort2021\$subFolders"

    foreach ($item in $childItem)
    {
        $itemPath = Get-ChildItem ($item.DirectoryName+ "\" + $item)

        foreach ($items in $itemPath)
        {
            if(Test-Path -Path $childItem)
            {
                $exists = $items.DirectoryName
                write-host "$items exist in $exists"
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

In the end, I want to take one single file from each of the folders, run it through all the folders and then basically tell me if the file is already in a folder or not.

I'd appreciate any help in this regard!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the "duplicated file" has the same name as the reference file? If not, it would require an md5sum or similar.

Comment: Essentially, I want to see if the file name of the items I've already copied out to the 88 folders already exists. 
So:
Go into first folder -> pick name of the first file -> run through all the other folders and see if it exists

Comment: Right, in your question you mentioned that you're _"left with 1 .pdf"_ however I don't see reference of that in your code, you should be using that item for the comparison.

Comment: instead of searching thru each dir ... just grab ALL the file names with `-Recurse` and `-File` ... and then search thru the resulting list.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already checked if the one I am left with already exists, and it does not. So I think I have taken a different .pdf and coped that into 2 folders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something robust (but time consuming) that should be able to find duplicates from your start position (even if the file name or extension has changed):

```bash
# Define the starting point
$ParentFolder = "\\pc90555\c$\Users\mmdu\OneDrive - COWI\Documents\kort2021" 

$duplicates = Get-ChildItem $ParentFolder -Recurse -File |
    Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Group-Object Hash |
        Where-Object Count -GT 1
```

Then, assuming it found a duplicate, you can inspect the `$duplicates` variables to get their paths:

```bash
PS /home/user/Documents> $duplicates[1]      

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 DA312CD92656EDCD5F7CF8DF… {Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman....

PS /home/user/Documents> $duplicates[1].Group

Algorithm       Hash                              Path
---------       ----                              ----
MD5             DA312CD92656EDCD5F7CF8DFB07CF0DC  /home/user/Documents/test.txt
MD5             DA312CD92656EDCD5F7CF8DFB07CF0DC  /home/user/Documents/test2.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to simply do this, breaking it into steps.

1. Recursively scan through the directory tree for `.pdf` files
2. Check the results of that to see if it contains your file where it shouldn't be

```
$myFileName = "ProposalDraft-Final.FINALv2.pdf"
$directoryToSearch = "\\pc90555\c$\Users\mmdu\OneDrive - COWI\"

$pdfFiles = Get-ChildItem -path $directoryToSearch -Include *.pdf
```

This leaves you with an array in `$pdfFiles` which has all the PDFs.  This is useful because it will have the full FileInfo, including the path, size, extension and other useful info.

Now to see if you put your file in too many places!

```
$pdfFiles | Where Name -eq $myFileName
```

The output will be an easy to read list showing the places where matching files were found.

In this example screenshot, I made a few directories and placed files with your desired name in each. You can see how the results are sorted by which directory they appear in, making it easy for you to find if there are duplicates.

[image: shows the output of a command to find files named ProposalDraft.pdf, which in this case were to be found in three different folders]

Comment: May I suggest using `-Filter` instead of `-Include`? If time is of the essence, you'd want to use the filesystem provider filter vs PowerShells filter.  You would also have to provide a wildcard at the end of the directory in order for `-Include` to work without the `-Recurse` switch.

Comment: Good suggestion!  Since -Filter relies on the underlying provider, I generally teach people to ignore the `Filter` switch unless they have some pressing speed need.  Why?  Because each provider is free to implement their own syntax which can differ from PowerShell's unifying syntax provided with the `Where-Object` cmdlet.  In my opinion, it's better to steer happy new guys away from that can of worms.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know the name of the duplicate file.
The files are something B2B-821312345.pdf and another could be B2B-7221334.pdf.
I am left with one, which means that it could be any of the 99 files that I have accidently duplicated one of