# Is there a way to get number of groups created by 'Group-Object' cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, csv, group-by, numbers

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but it keeps bugging me.

I have been tasked with finding duplicate files in certain location, recursively. I can do that with no problem. But seeing as some of the files have 3 or 4 duplicates I cannot answer the question of "How many files are originals?" without resorting to excel editing.

Code:

```
gci -path $path -recurse -file -erroraction silentlycontinue|
Select @{l='Original Filename';e={$_.PSChildName}}, @{l='Compare Filename';e={$_.BaseName.replace('_','*').replace(' ','*').replace('-','*')}}, @{l="Path";e={$_.PSParentPath.Substring(38,$_.PSParentPath.Length-38)}}, @{l="Link";e={$_.FullName}}|
group -Property 'Compare Filename'|
Where {$_.count -ge 2}|
%{$_.group}|
Export-Csv -Path $path2 -NoTypeInformation
```

Path variables are irrelevant, so I will not be listing them.

**EDIT:**
I have tested both of the provided resolutions, as well as read the marvelous explanation provided by mklement0.
In the end, at least with ~4k files I am working with, the speed of both resolutions is comparable. See below for the 'measure-command' output.

Expression-based
[image]

Pipeline-based
[image]

Comment: Please show us your source code using `Group-Object`. Use the command `help Group-Object -Full` and see `Example 1`.

Comment: The excel part is there only to provide background

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70380933/15339544 This method uses the file hash instead of the file names (slower but will find actual duplicates no matter their name).

Comment: Probably, and I will check it out, but that's besides the point. The question is "Is it possoble to get the number of groups crated by "group by" cmdlet?".

Comment: Previous comment didn't work. Try this: `Group -Property 'Compare Filename' | Measure | Select -ExpandProperty Count`

Comment: the `Group-Object` cmdlet gives a solitary `GroupInfo` object if there is only one group ... and gives a collection of `GroupInfo` objects if there is more than one. so ... force the result into an array & grab the `.Count` value. like this ... >>> `@(@($(1..20)) | Group-Object).Count` <<< as you might guess, the result is `20`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ***reliably* count the number of groups ([`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo) instances) that [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) outputs**, use either of the following:

- *Pipeline*-based, as suggested by [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42); while comparatively slow, this results in *streaming* processing that doesn't require collecting all `Group-Object` output in memory first:

```sh
(1, 1, 1 | Group-Object | Measure-Object).Count  # -> 1 (group)
```

- Concise, *expression*-based, as suggested by [Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey); note that this involves collecting all output objects in memory first:

```sh
@(1, 1, 1 | Group-Object).Count   # -> 1 (group)

# Alternative, using .Length
(1, 1, 1 | Group-Object).Length   # -> 1 (group)
```

Note:

- To count all original (non-duplicate) objects, i.e. those that are in a group of their own, simply append `| Where-Object Count -eq 1` to `Group-Object` above.
- The use of `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), is crucial in this case:  It ensures that the `Group-Object` output is considered an *array* even if only a *single* group happens to be output.

  - This ensures that it is the *array's* `.Count` property that is queried rather than a single `GroupInfo` instance's *own* `.Count` property - which reflects the count of members of the group, and would be `3` in the example above (try `(1, 1, 1 | Group-Object).Count`).
- Alternatively, using `.Length` instead of `.Count` bypasses this naming conflict: `.Length` and `.Count` are aliases of each other and are both provided as [intrinsic properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members?view=powershell-7.3#count-and-length) even on *scalars* (single objects), as part of the *unified handling of scalars and collections* in PowerShell: That is, PowerShell presents even any *single object* with `.Length` / `.Count` properties that indicate the count of that object, which by definition is `1` - *unless preempted by a type-native property of the same name*.

  - The intrinsic `.Length` property therefore works as expected, given that `GroupInfo` has no `.Length` property.
  - The inverse scenario can be demonstrated with a string scalar: `'foo'.Length` is `3` - the value of the type-native `.Length` property reflecting the character count - whereas `'foo'.Count` is `1` - the intrinsic `.Count` property that "counts" the single object.
- In the pipeline solution with [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) the problem doesn't arise due to the pipeline's enumeration behavior: however many objects `Group-Object` outputs are sent *one by one* through the pipeline, and `Measure-Object` counts them - and in this case the value of the type-native `.Count` property of the *always single* [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo) instance that `Measure-Object` outputs *is* the value of interest.

Comment: Is LINQ an option in addition to the ones mentioned? Just out of curiosity

Comment: @Santiago, `[Linq.Enumerable]::Count([object[]] (1, 1, 1 | Group-Object))` would work, but offers no benefits, as you could just do `([array] (1, 1, 1 | Group-Object)).Count`, or just `@(1, 1, 1 | Group-Object).Count`, as in the answer.